# Pass a value containing '&' in javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php

I have a javascript that pass the value from a select box to a php file via onchange.

This is how the values of the select box is listed:

```
foreach($config_group as $value){
    if($_SESSION['HOURLY_FT_WIP']['PROD_TESTER']==$value){
        echo "<option selected value='".$value."'>".$value."</option>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<option value='".$value."'>".$value."</option>";
    }
}
```

This is the script that pass the value to another php page:

```
function PROD_CHANGE_TESTER(){
    location_change = document.getElementById("PROD_SEL_TESTER").value;
    varURL = "http://" + varServerAddr +
        "/hourly_ft_wip/production_line/prod_line_tester.php?tester_change=" +
        location_change, LOAD(varURL, "TESTER");
    location.reload();
}
```

Now suppose a value `ASL1K & 4K`is selected from the select box. It arrives in the php page as:

```
$_REQUEST[4K] = ""
$_REQUEST[tester_change] = "ASL1K"
```

Well it looks like my varURL looks like this: `tester_change=ASL1K & 4K` so it put it in another place. Adding `/` may work to escape it. But the data is from the select that is made using foreach.

Comment: check it out : http://stackoverflow.com/a/332888/4786273

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encode URL in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) when generating urls in your code. This will encode the parts of your url with hex values, making sure there are no `&` or `?` in the added parameters

You would have to do this:

```
function PROD_CHANGE_TESTER(){
    location_change = document.getElementById("PROD_SEL_TESTER").value;
    varURL = "http://" + varServerAddr +
        "/hourly_ft_wip/production_line/prod_line_tester.php?tester_change=" +
        encodeURIComponent(location_change), encodeURIComponent(LOAD(varURL, "TESTER"));
    location.reload();
}
```

Comment: Thanks didn't know its a protocol to encode URL. Still new in javascript. Thanks. Will choose this as an answer when it's available.